# how to update xaml in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, rss, uwp

I have created a application for windows 10 (uwp) devices. I´m using the windows appstudio "designer". Now, I have to update the source code by a combobox and the correct eventhandler.
The combobox items contains different urls. After the selection changed, I have to parse entries from a url.

Layout-file:

```
<Page
x:Class="App.Pages.NeuigkeitenListPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:was_actions="using:AppStudio.Uwp.Actions"
xmlns:was_commands="using:AppStudio.Uwp.Commands"
xmlns:was_controls="using:AppStudio.Uwp.Controls"
xmlns:list_layouts="using:Wallfahrtsapp.Layouts.List"
xmlns:controls="App.Layouts.Controls"
xmlns:vm="using:App.ViewModels"
xmlns:triggers="using:App.Triggers"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=/Assets/Design/DesignData.json, Type=vm:DesignViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <was_controls:VisualBreakpoints x:Name="ResponsiveBehaviorsVBP" ConfigFile="/Assets/ResponsiveBehaviorsVBP.json"></was_controls:VisualBreakpoints>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{StaticResource AppBackground}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{StaticResource AppBarBackground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="48"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{Binding Active.pageTitleMargin, Source={StaticResource ResponsiveBehaviorsVBP}}" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.PageTitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource AppBarForeground}" FontSize="{StaticResource AppTitleTextSizeDefault}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" MaxLines="1"/>
    <was_actions:ActionsCommandBar 
        x:Name="appBar"
        ActionsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Actions}" Style="{StaticResource WasCommandBarStyle}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource AppBarForeground}"
        IsVisible="{x:Bind ViewModel.HasActions}"
        Background="{StaticResource AppBarBackground}"
        Grid.Row="{Binding Active.appBarRow, Source={StaticResource ResponsiveBehaviorsVBP}}"
        Grid.Column="{Binding Active.appBarColumn, Source={StaticResource ResponsiveBehaviorsVBP}}"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Active.appBarColumnSpan, Source={StaticResource ResponsiveBehaviorsVBP}}" Opened="appBar_Opened">
    </was_actions:ActionsCommandBar>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Height="3" Margin="0,6,0,6" IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="{StaticResource PageTitleForeground}" Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Collapsed, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <was_controls:ErrorNotificationControl x:Uid="ListErrorNotificationControl" Grid.Row="2" ErrorVisibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.HasLoadDataErrors, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" ErrorColor="{StaticResource PageTitleForeground}" Margin="10,0,18,0"/>
            <list_layouts:ListContactCard Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}" ItemClickCommand="{x:Bind ViewModel.ItemClickCommand}" OneRowModeEnabled="False" Margin="31,0,0,3" Grid.RowSpan="3" />

            <ListBox></ListBox>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       x:Name="source"
       TextWrapping="Wrap"
       Text="Newsquelle auswählen:"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
        FontStyle="Oblique"            
       Padding="40" Margin="384,-30,0,0" Height="78"
      />
    <ComboBox x:Name="sourceComboBox"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="200"
                SelectionChanged="selectionChanged"
                >
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Url1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Url2"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <controls:DataUpdateInformationControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" LastUpdateDateTime="{x:Bind ViewModel.LastUpdated, Mode=OneWay}" Color="{StaticResource PageTitleForeground}" Margin="8,4,8,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HasLocalData="{x:Bind ViewModel.HasLocalData}"/>
</Grid>
```

C#- file: Eventhandler

```
  private void selectionChanged (object sender , SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        index = sourceComboBox.SelectedIndex;
        Debug.WriteLine("selectionChangedEventMethod");
        newsblogHTTP(index);

    }
```

But how can I update my layout with the new content?
If you need more code snippets let´s see the repo for my project.

layout-file : https://github.com/MasterCoder1992/BlutWallfahrtWindows10/blob/version/march2k17Y/Wallfahrtsapp.W10/Pages/NeuigkeitenListPage.xaml

https://github.com/MasterCoder1992/BlutWallfahrtWindows10/blob/version/march2k17Y/Wallfahrtsapp.W10/Pages/NeuigkeitenListPage.xaml.cs

C#-Config file:
https://github.com/MasterCoder1992/BlutWallfahrtWindows10/blob/version/march2k17Y/Wallfahrtsapp.W10/Sections/NeuigkeitenConfig.cs

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am a bit confused about your requirement. You mean how to display the response of HTTP [request](http://blog.wallfahrt-wallduern-mobil.de)?

Comment: Yes and no . If I start the app, I get the entries from the RSS feed URL. This URL is stored in local settings. If I click on the "newslistpage" the combo box is displayed and the users could choose different sources. If I change the sources, I want to reload the same layout but with the new content.  I hope this description is better than the first one.